# How do I order double list of elements of this type: [[1,2,3], [a,b,c]]?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a double list of this type: `dl = [[13, 22, 41], ['c', 'b', 'a']]`, in which, each element `dl[0][i]` belongs a value in `dl[1][i]` (with the same index). How can I sort my list using dl[0] values as my order criteria, maintainning linked both sublists? Sublist are kind of 'linked data', so the previous dl[0][i] and dl[1][i] values must match their index after sorting the parent entire list, using as sorting criteria, the first sublist values

I expect something like:

input: `dl = [ [14,22,7,17], ['K', 'M', 'F','A'] ]`

output: `dl = [ [7, 14, 17, 22], ['F', 'K', 'A', 'M'] ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated for what you're looking for, selection sort but added another line to switch for the second list to match the first.

```
for i in range(len(dl[0])): 

    min_idx = i 
    for j in range(i+1, len(dl[0])): 
        if dl[0][min_idx] > dl[0][j]: 
            min_idx = j 

    dl[0][i], dl[0][min_idx] = dl[0][min_idx], dl[0][i]
    dl[1][i], dl[1][min_idx] = dl[1][min_idx], dl[1][i]
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself very well. Both list are kind of 'linked data', I mean, the value in dl[0][1] belongs to a value in dl[1][1], so, after sorting the entire list, indexes of both values must match.

Comment: @adabreug94 Are you looking for efficiency? If not then you can just implement a simple selection sort algorithm and switch the values at the same time it is sorted by the first.

Comment: @c-smith, how would you do it? I tried implementing a variant of QuickSort but it got fuzzy and confussing.

Comment: @adabreug94 Check the solution again, I updated it using selection sort and it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

This was way too much fun to write. I don't doubt that this function can be greatly improved, but this is what I've gotten in a very short amount of time and should get you started.

I've included some tests just so you can verify that this does indeed do what you want.

```py
from unittest import TestCase, main


def sort_by_first(data):
    sorted_data = []

    for seq in data:
        zipped_to_first = zip(data[0], seq)
        sorted_by_first = sorted(zipped_to_first)
        unzipped_data = zip(*sorted_by_first)
        sorted_data.append(list(tuple(unzipped_data)[1]))

    return sorted_data


class SortByFirstTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_sort(self):
        output_1 = sort_by_first([[1, 3, 5, 2, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']])
        self.assertEqual(output_1, [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c']])

        output_2 = sort_by_first([[9, 1, 5], [21, 22, 23], ['spam', 'foo', 'bar']])
        self.assertEqual(output_2, [[1, 5, 9], [22, 23, 21], ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That's a good idea. You don't even need `itemgetter` though, you could just use the standard, lexicographical sort for sequences.

Comment: You're totally right. I didn't take too much time to check things, I just knew that `itemgetter` would work and threw it in.

Comment: And if you accept a list of tuples, you could use `list(zip(*sorted(list(zip(*[[9, 1, 5], [21, 22, 23], ['spam', 'foo', 'bar']])))))` directly, without any explicity loop.

Comment: I did originally write it all on one comprehension, but I felt that was quite difficult to read, so I refactored it into a loop.

Comment: true. I like the symmetry of the methods, I don't like the two brackets followed by five parens. :) keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You can try solving this with a for loop also:

```
dl = [ [3,2,1], ['c', 'b', 'a'] ]
for i in range(0,len(dl)):
    dl[i].sort()
print(dl)
```